# Table View selection and pan gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a table view with a pan gesture on it. When I start panning the tableview up and down the tableView selection gets disable and I can't select tableview cells.

```
UIPanGesture* tablePanGesture =[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
tablePanGesture.delegate = self;
[tableView addGestureRecognizer:tablePanGesture];
[tablePanGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

And I using the following delegate to let my gestures and tableview gestures work together:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return YES;
}
```

I have implemented the method for table view  didSelectRowAtIndexPath but when I use panning it is not called.
 Is there any conflict between pan gesture and tableview Delegate?

Comment: why are you using pan gestures

Comment: @LalitKumar I want to pan the table up and then enable the scroll and then pan it down if the content offset is zero and table is dragging.

Comment: What is purpose of doing this  ??

Comment: @NJGadhiya I have a tableview which shows a list to user and I want the user to be able to shrink the tableview and then scroll it

Comment: You can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` method to detect up/down scroll of `UITableView`. So you can remove the pan gesture if the scroll delegate did the purpose.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I want to use both table view scroll and panning in different table view position

Comment: One way to do this is implement `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognize` and `Return NO;`if it is not scrolling.

Comment: @NJGadhiya thanks but is not helping me, if I say:  if (tableview.scrollEnable == NO)- return NO, it will disable the gestures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are missing this line:-**

```
[tablePanGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

This will let the  UIPanGesture recognize the pan gesture  and also pass the touch to the next responder means your table view select or tap.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried to add it but it is not working, would you please explain more where I need to add this?

Comment: Can u update the code .. where you have added  this `tablePanGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];` line.

Comment: Updated, I tried to add it in different places but it is not working.

Comment: This works for me on Swift 4.2. The reason why the scenario doesn't work for the OP is because the gesture was added directly on to the tableview. You can see this in line 3 of his first block of formatted code. I tried both methods - on the tableview and on the ViewController view, adding to the ViewController View allows the PanGesture to work in conjunction with the tableview touches.